# Why is the option to leave a chat missing in MS Teams?

Tags: windows-10, chat, microsoft-teams

I can see a "Leave Chat" option in other chats that I'm a part of but not this particular one.

[image]

There originally were 3 persons in the chat. One left. And I no longer need to be in it. Is there a setting somewhere that I need to enable?

For the record, I'm not the organizer of this chat but was rather added in by someone else.

Comment: I don't have Teams in front of me, isn't the icon with the arrow and the rectangle the exit chat button?

Comment: @ramhound that's share screen button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leave a GROUP chat, so enable others to continue discussion without you.

However, at least two people need to stay, otherwise it wouldn't be a chat anymore.

You can hide a chat if you don't want to see it.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. But it still sucks. especially that group chats with only 2 persons have exactly the same name as 1 to 1 chat with the same person. This results in 2 chats with the same chat name in the list. This is really confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this thread looking for an answer to this question regarding a user not having the option to leave a chat that had lots of members.

Turns out that this option is only available to users who were added with the **Include all chat history** option enabled.

[See the add dialog here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeFQF.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).